# XML: where to keep my own format's version

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I creating "Notes application" and I want to have the ability to format note's content. I decided to use XML with my own format:

```
<note>
    <block>
        <text>
            some text _some text_ **some text**
        </text>
    </block>
    <block>
        <image path="XXXXX_XXX_XXX.png"/>
    </block>
</note>
```

And I want to keep a version of format somewhere. For example, in the new version of the format, I can rename `block` to `element` and then change `formatVersion` from `1.0` to `1.1`. Where must I put version String?

Must it be note's attribute?

```
<note formatVersion="1.1">
<note/>
```

or should I keep it out of XML?
For example, in Note object

```
-----------------------
|         Note        |
-----------------------
|- noteXml: String    |
|- formatVersion: int |
-----------------------
```

Comment: I wonder which XML version `<text/>` is supposed to be.

Comment: @MartinHonnen can you explain what do you mean? `<text><text/>` is custom tag that will be deserialized into `TextElement` object.

Comment: The right XML syntax is e.g. `<text>...</text>`, not `<text>...<text/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for your correction. Fixed.

Comment: Could you be talking about namespaces or schemas?

Comment: @Alexandr  Are you storing multiple notes in the same file, or one note per file?

Comment: @dbasnett notes are stored in db(note per row). XML string is just a column cell.

Answer (score 1):

Where the version goes depends on what flexibility you want.  Here are some ideas.

```
    'one note per file
    Dim note As XElement
    note = <note formatVersion="1.1">
               <block>
                   <text>some text _some text_ **some text**</text>
               </block>
               <block>
                   <image path="XXXXX_XXX_XXX.png"/>
               </block>
           </note>

    'multiple notes per file
    Dim notes As XElement
    notes = <notes formatVersion="1.1">
                <note noteName="one">
                    <block>
                        <text>some text _some text_ **some text**</text>
                    </block>
                    <block>
                        <image path="XXXXX_XXX_XXX.png"/>
                    </block>
                </note>
                <note noteName="two">
                    <block>
                        <text>some text _some text_ **some text**</text>
                    </block>
                    <block>
                        <image path="XXXXX_XXX_XXX.png"/>
                    </block>
                </note>
            </notes>
```

In the multi note example you could add versioning to each note.

Comment: Different notes can be created with the different formats(in different versions of app). The first solution looks acceptable. I have two ways: store version as note's attribute or in db note's column.